# Converting a dataframe column to date dataype

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a column in data frame that contains years and it is stored as object datatype. It has values such as 1931to32,2009-10,1956-57,1951~52,1955-56,2017~18, I tried  to change them in to a consistent format "yyyy" using pandas.
df['TeamLaunch']  contains values such as 1931to32,2009-10,1956-57,1951~52,1955-56,2017~18, need to make make them uniform and consistent in the same format "1931,2009,1956,1951,1955,2017.

```
Tired this code, couldn't able to convert to "yyyy" format 
df['TeamLaunch'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TeamLaunch'], format="%Y"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible simplify problem by extract first 4 values of strings use:

```
df['TeamLaunch'] = df['TeamLaunch'].str[:4]
```

Or if need extract first year with 4 digits use:

```
df['TeamLaunch'] = df['TeamLaunch'].str.extract('(\d{4})')
```

Last convert to datetimes:

```
df['TeamLaunch'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TeamLaunch'], format="%Y")
```

If possible some values are not correct 4 digits use:

```
df['TeamLaunch'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TeamLaunch'], format="%Y", errors='coerce')
```